# What is the NetMQ API for receiving in a custom buffer in order to avoid creating a new byte array on each frame/message?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq, netmq

I have the following code:

```
while (!isCancellationRequested)
{
    byte[] frameBytes = socket.ReceiveFrameBytes();
    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.Deserialize(frameBytes);
    // send the data somewhere somehow...
}
```

What I want to do, but I can't find in the documentation is something that will avoid the creation of new byte array on each `socket.Receive`:

```
byte[] frameBytes = new byte[123];
while (!isCancellationRequested)
{
    socket.ReceiveFrameBytes(frameBytes);
    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.Deserialize(frameBytes);
    // send the data somewhere somehow...
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get high performance and zero allocation with NetMQ you need to both enable the BufferPool and use the Msg structure directly.

```
BufferPool.SetBufferManagerBufferPool(1024 * 1024, 1024);    

while (!isCancellationRequested)
{
    Msg msg = new Msg();
    msg.InitEmpty();
    socket.Receive(ref msg);
    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.Deserialize(msg.Data, msg.Size);
    msg.Close();
    // send the data somewhere somehow...
}
```